# How to permutate two lists in Python

Tags: python

Here are two examples of lists

```
list = [["mo", "thu"], ["we", "fri"], ["mo", "mo"]]
list2 = [["mo", "fri", "fri"], ["we", "we"]]
```

So these lists come in random order. I've given two examples here. What I want to do is compute all possible ways these lists can be permutated. On the level where it's list[1] * list[2] * list[3]. All possible combinations. A smaller example what I would like to reach is this:

```
list3 = [["we", "thu"],["fri", "thu"]]
```

-->

```
[["we", "fri"], ["we", "thu"], ["thu", "fri"], ["thu", "thu"]]
```

Also, the lists are random so the amount of elements in the list or the nested lists can vary. I can python this out by alot of code but I was hoping there is an easier way to this.

Cheers

Comment: Based on your `list3` example, I assume order doesn't matter?

Comment: No, order does not matter

Answer (score 8):

What you want is unclear but maybe what you want is the cartesian product of your list? If so, it is very simple:

```
list3 = [["we", "thu"],["fri", "thu"]]
import itertools
final_list = [list(v) for v in itertools.product(*list3)]
## [['we', 'fri'], ['we', 'thu'], ['thu', 'fri'], ['thu', 'thu']]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks alot!